# Copy an element of array of objects to new array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using NodeJs to create my own API based from Twitter API.
The problem is that:
I have this array of object from Twitter API. It looks something like this.

```
[
  {
    ...
    text: "100% I am sleeping ...",
    user: {
       screen_name: "Ninja",
    },
    ...
  },
  {},
  ...
]
```

I want know how can I take each "text" and "screen_name" form the list above and store it in a new array of object, to look like this:

```
[
  {
    text: "",
    screen_name: ""
  },
  {},
  {},
  ...
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: Please also use proper words, not txtspk.

Comment: Use array,map function info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Array.map**

```js
let arr = [{text: "100% I am sleeping ...",user: {screen_name:"Ninja"}}];

let result = arr.map(({text, user : {screen_name}}) => ({text, screen_name}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array map `method`. This will return a new array of objects having desired keys

```js
var api = [{
    text: "100% I am sleeping ...",
    user: {
      screen_name: "Ninja",
    },
    somOtherVal: 'otherVal1'

  },
  {
    text: "100% I am sleeping ...",
    user: {
      screen_name: "Ninja",
    },
    somOtherVal: 'otherVal'
  }
]

let newApi = api.map(function(item) {
  return {

    text: item.text,
    screen_name: item.user.screen_name
  }

});
console.log(newApi)
```

Comment: `user: item.user` should be `screen_name: item.user.screen_name`